# InvalidOperationException in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, winforms, entity-framework

InvalidOperationException occurred when tried to add a new object in the edit mode of a transaction which described the details as given below:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The existing object is in the Unchanged state. An object can only be added to the ObjectStateManager again if it is in the added state

Here is the code:

I am getting the error in the following line:

```
model.AddToGRNDets(ObjG);
```

model is an EF object, ObjG is an object of class GRNDet and I am trying to add an object to GRNDet table in edit mode of a transaction.

Comment: how to share the code the chars are limited to 600

Comment: Why 600? Sometime people post hundreds lines of code. Try, will see. There should be no problem for this. Stackoverflow is the place to post your code.

Comment: Ok now why so much lines? If you can post hundreds of lines it doesn't mean you really should do it. Please narrow down your code posted to the scope of the problem only.